# Make horizontal colorscale of plot?

Tags: r, colorbar

I have a spatial plot with default colorbar/colorscale which is vertical. The problem is that I want to make it becomes horizontal bar located in the bottom of my plot. Is there anybody know how to do that? Please give me feedback.
Thank you.

```
windows()
image.plot(x=lon, y=lat, inputvar,
xlim=c(12,25), ylim=c(44,50),
col=colorscale, breaks=brks, lab.breaks=brks,
xlab="Longitude (deg)", ylab="Latitude (deg)")
title(main="Seasonal Relative Bias RR20 SON")   #Bias Difference
mtext("%", side=4, adj=0.5,line=0.4)
map(database="world",add=TRUE)
# make grid lines
abline(h=seq(44,50,1), v=seq(12,24,2),lty=2,col="grey",lwd=0.5)
# text(x=26, y=47, "Bias %", xpd=T)
```

[image]

Comment: What packages are you using? `image.plot` is not a base R function.

Comment: Its from library(fields)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the argument [`horizontal`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fields/versions/14.1/topics/image.plot):

> If false (default) legend will be a vertical strip on the right side.
> If true the legend strip will be along the bottom.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(fields)

x<- 1:10
y<- 1:15
z<- outer( x,y,"+") 
image.plot(x,y,z, horizontal = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>